# How To Print Array inside Json Object

Tags: javascript, json

I got this Json String

```
{ "Banks": [ 
  { "BankNo": "TEST 5", "Name": "MAY", "Account": "987654", "BankCode": "ICBK", "Branch": "MAY" }, 
  { "BankNo": "TEST 6", "Name": "PETER", "Account": "987653", "BankCode": "ABOC", "Branch": "PETER" }, 
  { "BankNo": "TEST 7", "Name": "DAVID", "Account": "987652", "BankCode": "PCBC", "Branch": "DAVID" }, 
  { "BankNo": "TEST 8", "Name": "JOHN", "Account": "987651", "BankCode": "CMBC", "Branch": "JOHN" } 
] }
```

I try many way to print it out but fail... How I can loop one by one inside this Json?

The Result I expected is
1st Loop Print out 
BankNo : TEST 5

2nd Loop Print out 
BankNo : TEST 6

Comment: The array is assigned to a property named `Banks`. Once you parse the JSON string into an object, you can access it by that name and loop through it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var jn = { "Banks": [ { "BankNo": "TEST 5", "Name": "MAY", "Account": "987654", "BankCode": "ICBK", "Branch": "MAY" }, { "BankNo": "TEST 6", "Name": "PETER", "Account": "987653", "BankCode": "ABOC", "Branch": "PETER" }, { "BankNo": "TEST 7", "Name": "DAVID", "Account": "987652", "BankCode": "PCBC", "Branch": "DAVID" }, { "BankNo": "TEST 8", "Name": "JOHN", "Account": "987651", "BankCode": "CMBC", "Branch": "JOHN" } ] }

//getting banks array
var banks = jn.Banks

banks.forEach((bank)=> {
console.log(`${bank.BankNo}: ${bank.Name}`)
})
```